# Set MySQL variables via argument in Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'd like to configure the `ft_min_word_len` and `ft_stopword_file` settings in my MySQL container. I need shorter words to be indexed as fulltext, and I don't want to use a stopword file at all.

I tried to set the variables with arguments in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  ata-mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    command:
      - "mysqld"
      - "--innodb_buffer_pool_size=400M"
      - "--innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1"
      - "--ft_min_word_len=1"
      - "--ft_stopword_file=''"
```

But after a restart, it looks like MySQL hasn't picked up this configuration:

```
mysql> show variables like 'ft_min_word_len';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| ft_min_word_len | 4     |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'ft_stopword_file';
+------------------+------------+
| Variable_name    | Value      |
+------------------+------------+
| ft_stopword_file | (built-in) |
+------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Is it possible to set those variables through an argument? I'd like to avoid creating a separate Dockerfile for this kind of configuration.

Comment: Use a read-only volume to a custom `my.cnf` in your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out, the command line format for this options uses dashes, and not underscores.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file

So, the settings must look like this

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  ata-mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    command:
      - "mysqld"
      - "--innodb_buffer_pool_size=400M"
      - "--ft-min_word-len=1"
      - "--ft-stopword-file=''"
```

**Important:** Only after I dropped and re-added the index, the settings took effect.

BTW: For InnoDB these two options are `--innodb-ft-min-token-size` and `--innodb-ft-enable-stopword`

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_enable_stopword

Answer (score -1):

Well, you're making it harder on yourself by avoiding Dockerfile ENV parameters or my.cnf file methods.

The problem with your setup is that each line within the array will be handled as a separated command like "mysqld" then "--innodb_buffer_pool_size=400M" and so on, which causes the unexpected behavior.

The correct way is to apply the command in your docker-compose.yml as a one line command like this:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  data-mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    command:
      - "mysqld --innodb_buffer_pool_size=400M --innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1 --ft_min_word_len=1 --ft_stopword_file=''"
```

Or you may use the docker compose environment option like this:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  data-mysql:
    environment:
      - EXAMPLE=EXAMPLE
      - EXAMPLE=EXAMPLE
      - EXAMPLE=EXAMPLE
```

And you can get the list of MYSQL ENV from here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/environment-variables.html

Comment: I don't think that's true, you can write a command as an array, see https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#command

And because YAML parses multiple lines with a leading `-` as an array, this works. I can confirm this by looking at the actual command. `docker ps --no-trunc` shows me the following command: `"docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld --innodb_buffer_pool_size=400M --innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1 --ft_min_word_len=1 --ft_stopword_file=''"`

Unfortantely, the MYSQL ENV Variables don't include settings for the fulltext index.